# Using RESTful source instead of static JSON in AngularJS

Tags: angularjs, json

I have the following code which displays a static JSON object in a grid.

```
var app = angular.module('app', ['ui.bootstrap']);
app.controller('ModalInstanceCtrl', function($scope, $modalInstance, customer) {
  $scope.customer = customer;
});

app.controller('CustomerController', function($scope, $timeout, $modal, $log) {

  $scope.customers = [{
    name: 'Movie Title 1',
    details: 'http://image.tmdb.org/t/p/w342//lFSSLTlFozwpaGlO31OoUeirBgQ.jpg',
  }, {
    name: 'Movie Title 2',
    details: 'http://image.tmdb.org/t/p/w342//tgfRDJs5PFW20Aoh1orEzuxW8cN.jpg',
  }, {
    name: 'Movie Title 3',
    details: 'http://image.tmdb.org/t/p/w342//wJXku1YhMKeuzYNEHux7XtaYPsE.jpg',
  }];

  // MODAL WINDOW
  $scope.open = function(_customer) {

    var modalInstance = $modal.open({
      controller: "ModalInstanceCtrl",
      templateUrl: 'myModalContent.html',
      resolve: {
        customer: function() {
          return _customer;
        }
      }
    });
  };
});
```

I need to be able to use this RESTful API source:

```
$http.get("http://api.themoviedb.org/3/movie/now_playing?api_key=ebea8cfca72fdff8d2624ad7bbf78e4c")
    .success(function(response) {
      console.log(response);
      $scope.results = response.results;
    });
```

and enable the click event to trigger the modal as it does now, except it needs to grab the details of each of the items in the JSON object and display in the modal.

The `ng-repeat`:

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <div ng-repeat="items in results">
      <img class="col-lg-3 col-md-3 col-sm-3 col-xs-12 thumbnail" ng-src="http://image.tmdb.org/t/p/w342/{{items.poster_path}}">
      </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Using this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/8s9ss/224/ as a base, I need to have the buttons replaced by the images coming through the REST API and they should trigger a modal on click.

Comment: I don't see any REST calls in your fiddle

Comment: I've added it to line 10 here: http://jsfiddle.net/8s9ss/225/

Comment: I'm not sure I can follow you here, so you want to display a list of customers. What do you want to do with the REST call results? As far as I can see there's no full image urls in those results either?

Comment: No, the customers was an example to show how data could be displayed. The customers data and any association to it in the modal should be replaced by the REST call results. The results image path is only partial, but has a base URL that in the end should look like this: `ng-src="http://image.tmdb.org/t/p/w342/{{items.poster_path}}`

Comment: Using `ng-click="open(items)"` seems to work just fine (with a minor tweak to your modal template) ~ http://jsfiddle.net/8s9ss/226/. Just be wary that one of the titles doesn't have a `poster_path` property so the image won't show correctly

Comment: @Phil - Thank you! Just what I needed. I know about the one or two `poster_path` returning a null value. I was considering showing the title in its place, but not sure how. Any additional help there would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: You could have a backup *dummy* image or other element and use `ng-hide="items.poster_path"` on that and `ng-if="items.poster_path"` on the image you currently have. See http://jsfiddle.net/8s9ss/227/

Answer (score 0):

This should be all you need

```
<div ng-repeat="items in results">
  <a ng-click="open(items)" class="col-lg-3 col-md-3 col-sm-3 col-xs-12 thumbnail">
    <img ng-if="items.poster_path" ng-src="http://image.tmdb.org/t/p/w342/{{items.poster_path}}">
    <div class="caption" ng-hide="items.poster_path">
      <h3>{{items.title}}</h3>
    </div>
  </a>
</div>
```

You'll need to tweak your modal template to show the different properties but you should be able to figure it out.

http://jsfiddle.net/8s9ss/229/